# Python: How to pass row and next row DataFrame.apply() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have DataFrame with thousands rows. Its structure is as below

> ```
>      A    B    C     D 
>  0   q   20    'f'
>  1   q   14    'd'
>  2   o   20    'a'
> ```

I want to compare the A column of current row and next row. If those values are equal I want to add the value of B column which has lower the value to D column of compared row which has greater value. Then I want to remove the moved column value of column B. It's like a swap process.

> ```
>     A    B    C     D 
> 0   q   20    'f'   14
> 1   o   20    'a'
> ```

I have thousands rows and iloc, loc, at methods work slow. At least I want to use DataFrame apply method. I tried some code samples but they didn't work.

I want to do something as below:
DataFrame.apply(lambda row: self.compare(row, next(row)), axis=1))

I have a compare method but I couldn't pass next row to the compare method. How can I pass it to the method? Also I am open to hear faster pandas solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best not to do that with `apply` as it will be slow; you can look at using `shift`, e.g.

```py
df['A_shift'] = df['A'].shift(1)
df['Is_Same'] = 0
df.loc[df.A_shift == df.A, 'Is_Same'] = 1
```

Gets a bit more complicated if you're doing the shift within groups, but still possible.